# Customising audio on an arcade game with U6295 audio IC

Tags: audio, sound, pcm, eprom

I have an arcade redemption game that has a U6295 audio IC that plays 4 different soundtracks which are stored on a ST M27C801 EPROM.

I would like to flash my own audio onto that EPROM with one of those universal EPROM programmers so the machine can play it, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it. What programs would I need to install to get my .wav audio files onto that EPROM.

I'm happy to take photos of the board in the machine if required. There isn't a schematic diagram for it though...

Comment: What wav format is currently used on the EPROMs?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's currently programmed, do you know how I can figure that out?

Comment: It may not even be wav format. You need to figure this out. There might be dozens of likely formats even ones that are bespoke to the device.

Comment: Would there be a way I could read this from the EPROM in the machine?

Comment: If it's a standard enough type, you should be able to read it with most EEPROM reader/writers.